# Split in python with character special

Tags: python, split

I split within a string traversing an array with values, this split must contain the following rule:

- Split the string into two parts when there is a special character, and select the first part as a result;

**SCRIPT**

```
array = [
'srv1 #s',
'srv2;192.168.9.1'
]

result = []
for x in array:

  outfinally = [line.split(';')[0] and line.split()[0] for line in x.splitlines() if line and line[0].isalpha()]

  for srv in outfinally:
      if srv != None:
          result.append(srv)

for i in result:
  print(i)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
srv1
srv2;192.168.9.1
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
srv1
srv2
```

Comment: Also, you can use `if not srv` to check for `None`s automatically.

Comment: Do you want to split on _any_ special charracter? Not only on space or `;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should split on any special charters and append the first part of the split to a new list:

```
array = [
'srv1 #s',
'srv2;192.168.9.1'
]

sep = (r'[`\-=~!@#$%^&*()_+\[\]{};\'\\:"|<,./<>?]')
rest = text.split(sep, 1)[0]
new_array =[]
for i in array:
    new_array.append(re.split(sep,i)[0])
```

Output:

```
['srv1 ', 'srv2']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split twice with the two different separators instead:

```
result = [s.split()[0].split(';')[0] for s in array]
```

`result` becomes:

```
['srv1', 'srv2']
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here: `line.split(';')[0] and line.split()[0]`

Your *second* condition splits on whitespace. As a result, it'll always return the whitespace-split version unless there's a semicolon at the start of the input (in which case you get empty string).

You probably want to chain the two splits instead:

`line.split(';')[0].split()[0]`

---

To see what the code in your question is doing, take a look at what your conditional expression does in a few different cases:

```
array = ['srv1 s', 'srv2;192.168.9.1', ';192.168.1.1', 'srv1;srv2 192.168.1.1']

>>> for item in array:
...   print("Original: {}\n\tSplit: {}".format(item, item.split(';')[0] and item.split()[0]))
...
Original: srv1 s
        Split: srv1 # split on whitespace
Original: srv2;192.168.9.1
        Split: srv2;192.168.9.1 # split on whitespace!
Original: ;192.168.1.1
        Split: # split on special char, returned empty which is falsey, returns empty str
Original: srv1;srv2 192.168.1.1
        Split: srv1;srv2 # split only on whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
outfinally = [line.split(';')[0] and line.split()[0] for line in x.splitlines() if line and line[0].isalpha()]
```

To

```
outfinally = [line.replace(';', ' ').split()[0] for line in x.splitlines() if line and line[0].isalpha()]
```

When you use `and` like that, it will always return the first result as long as the first result is truthy. The split function returns the full string in a list when a match is not found. Since it's returning something truthy, you'll never move on to the second condition (and if you use `or` like I first tried to do, you'll always move on to the second condition). Instead of having 2 conditions, what you'll have to do is combine them into one. Something like `line.replace(';', ' ').split()[0]` or blhsing's solution is even better.